# Infinite Scrolling creates pagination sublink as I scroll

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I've finally worked out Infinite Scrolling thanks to what **lharby** has commented on my last post.
**Thank you so much!**
 The problem is that the script creates a new pagination link as I exceeded scrolling for 15 posts (the amount of posts-per-page that I set for my Tumblr)
**f.e :** assets.txmblr.com =======> assets.txmblr.com **/page/(2;3;4;...)**
Thank you for the help !

Code (line 210 -> line 225)

```
        <script>
window.onload = function() {
var elem = document.getElementById('content');
let infScroll = new InfiniteScroll(elem, {
path: '.pagination__next',
append: '.post'
});
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
{block:NextPage}
<a href="{NextPage}" class="pagination__next"></a>
{/block:NextPage}
```

Comment: It looks like everything is working correctly as far as I can tell? Can you screenshot the issue. Infinite scrolling is working, you don't need pagination if IS is present, and the page urls are being updated as you scroll. For other users who check this it would also be useful to add your blog link to this question.

Comment: You would need to download the script file and modify it, and then either upload it inside your theme (and remove the reference to the current script) or host it somewhere you can refer to it in your template. You also really need access to the unminified (source) version of the file if you can find it, I might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good news, I downloaded the full zip package here: https://infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-docs.zip

On lines 1340 to 1343 is the call to the function to update the url

```
// update URL
proto.onPageLoadHistory = function( response, path ) {
  this.setHistory( response.title, path );
};
```

If you comment this out I believe the page will no longer refresh the url.

However as stated you need to download the file, modify it, then either host it or put it in your theme. If you add it into the theme you would want to minify it first.